# Use python code for build android app in android studio

Tags: android, python, android-library

i have some python code and it is chatbot and i'm looking for a way to use those python code inside the android project there any way to do this?
Please help...

Comment: refer this qpython.com/

Comment: Why can't you port the bot to c++ or java? Kivy is not 100 percent tested and you may have some issues

Answer (score 4):

There are two main tools to use, that are different from each other:

- [QPython](http://qpython.com/)
- [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)

With Kivy, roughly the same code can be deployed to IOS as well.